# SQL select statement avoiding duplicated rows based on primary key

Tags: sql, postgresql

I have a table employee with two columns-empid(primary key), name. Suppose it has below three rows.

```
EmpID   Name
---------------
11      Name1
12      Name2
11      Name3
```

How would I write a select statement to select records avoiding the two rows which have duplicating empid. I used query like:

```
select empid, name 
from(select empid, name, row_number() over(partition by empid order by empid desc) rnk
    from t)a 
where a.rnk=1
```

But this query will give

```
EmpID   Name
---------------
11      Name1
12      Name2
```

As the result. But all I need is

```
EmpID   Name
---------------
12      Name2
```

Comment: Well, if empid is a primary key, how come you have duplicate values in it?

Comment: Just change `row_number()` for `count()` and you should get the result you need.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

try this query, this will work and give you the row 12 Name2

select empid, name from employee a 
join (
select empid , count(empid) as count1 from employee 
group by empid
having count(empid)=1 ) b on a.empid=b.empid

Answer (score 0):

Would not `SELECT max(empid) as empid, name from employee group by name having count(distinct empid) < 2` work?

Answer (score 0):

```
select empid, name 
from(select empid, name,count(*) over(partition by empid) cnt from t) t 
where cnt=1
```

Answer (score 0):

An [anti join](http://www.credativ.co.uk/credativ-blog/2010/02/postgresql-optimizer-bits-semi-and-anti-joins) using `NOT EXISTS` might be the fastest approach:

```
SELECT  empID, Name
FROM    T
WHERE   NOT EXISTS (SELECT 1 FROM T AS T2 WHERE T2.EmpID = T.EmpID AND T2.Name <> T.Name);
```

I have done no testing, so it is possible that the optimiser might be able to generate a anti semi-join using a `count = 1` operation, but this gives it the best possible chance of getting to that plan.

Comment: are we all going to ignore the fact that there is something wrong when there are duplicate values in a PK column? there should not be a need for this SQL string in the first place. or am I wrong?

Comment: I have over looked this fact because it doesn't seem relevant to answering the question at hand - *"How would I write a select statement to select records avoiding the two rows which have duplicating empid"* - Yes it is an important thing to point out, and I have upvoted your comment, but it doesn't alter the solution to the actual question asked. In the interest of being helpful I posted the solution in spite of the possible misunderstanding on behalf of the asker.